# draggable element becomes null

Tags: javascript, html

I have made [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mLorpscj/) which is based of a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZ45HZAkbLc&ab_channel=TylerPotts) i followed and i've tried to add some more functionality to it myself, so i can add tasks when i click on the button, which works fine, but the issue occurs when i try to drag one of the added elements, it loses the value and just prints null and also loses the class i've assigned to it.

```
    function addItem() {
    var newItem = document.createElement("div");
    newItem.className = "list-item";
    newItem.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
    newItem.draggable = true;
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(newItem).appendChild(text);
}
```

My end goal is to make it look like the hard coded task and im sure i can achieve this, but i just dont understand why the value and class is lost when i drag the element.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the HTML, it looks like you're close, but the elements you're generating with your add item button aren't structurally the same as the one that you're trying to imitate. The "standard" item has an  nested inside it - not just simply inner html/text.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that i understand what you mean. Do i need to make sure when creating an element that it is the exact same as the element it is based on?